# How to write active record query to details by using and

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i have two tables

1)Properties :fields  are id, name, propert_type,category_id

2)Admins : fields id, name,mobile,category_id

i want to write an active record to list all properties , where category_id in properties table and category_id in Admins table are equal, according to current_user_id

i am listing this property list by logging as admin.

model relation

`class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :admins,dependent: :destroy
    has_many :properties,dependent: :destroy
end`

`class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :properties
end`

`class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :admin
    belongs_to :category
end`

i wrote active record like this , but i got error,
can anyone please suggest me a solution for this

`@properties= Property.where('properties.category_id=?','admins.category_id=?').and('admins.id=?',current_user.specific.id)`

Comment: An admin has_many properties?

Comment: What is the relation between properties and admins?

Comment: admin has_many:properties, property belongs_to :admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your assosciation,You can use a sub query for getting your result in one line

```js
@properties = Property.where(category_id: Admin.select("category_id").where(id: current_user.id))
```

Comment: i want to list category_id according to current _user, this query gives every category_id in property table matching with every category_id field in admins.

Comment: howz category related to them?

Comment: yes, admin belongs_to :category, and property belongs_to:category

Comment: is that you required?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103822/discussion-between-sree-and-sravan).

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding `current_user` is an `Admin`. So You can search by the `category_id` of `current_user`. If I'm right, try this

```
@properties = Property.where(category_id: current_user.category_id)
```